# Delete[] c++ not working

Tags: c++, delete-operator

```
void show(int* x){
    printf("%d",x[3]);
}

int main(){
    int* ptr;

    ptr = new int[9]();
    delete [] ptr;    


    printf("%d %d\n", ptr[7], *(ptr+7));
    show(ptr);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: consider providing more information, and a question

Comment: does "not working" mean you can still output the values? this might just be a case of undefined behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Karthik is right - what's not working? (I see all kinds of bugs in this code, but which one are you concerned about?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer to deallocated location Is it a Undefined Behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662587/pointer-to-deallocated-location-is-it-a-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As you can probably see from the comments, you are expected to provide a clear question. In this case, something of the form "I do X (code sample), I expect to get Y, but I observe Z. Why is that?"

Comment: "My code has a bug in it. Why doesn't it do what I expect?" Umm,  ... because it has a bug. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you think it's not working? You allocate 9 integers, then you delete them. That works just fine.

The problem is that you then access those deleted integers. What happens once you do is irrelevant - you're in undefined behavior land. It may show the old values, it may crash or the Universe may begin contracting.

Answer (score 4):

You are invoking **undefined behaviour** by accessing elements of a deleted dynamically allocated array. There is no "not working" here, because *anything* can happen. `ptr` points to the same memory address as before the `delete`, and there is nothing to say what could be at that location when you try to access it.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer is not invalidated after `delete[]`, but the heap memory pointed to is freed so it cannot be trusted any more. This type of code typically causes headaches in a parallel system.

You can avoid this by nulling the pointer right after deletion:

```
delete[] ptr;
ptr = 0;
```